# Using LINQ to get values from Stored Procedure

Tags: c#, sql, linq, stored-procedures

I am using LINQ and DataContext to retrieve my data. I do not use the Entity Framework. And now I have a stored procedure which I do not know

1. how to provide parameters and
2. how to define and get the result from (single value).

The stored procedure is defined this way:

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[spGetConvertedFieldValue] 
-- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @Table NVARCHAR(50),
    @Field NVARCHAR(50),
    @Key NVARCHAR(50),
    @KeyValue NVARCHAR(500)
AS
BEGIN
-- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
-- interfering with SELECT statements.
SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX)

    SET @SQL = 'SELECT ' + @Field + ' FROM ' + @Table + ' WHERE ' + @Key + ' = ''' + @KeyValue + ''''

EXEC(@SQL)
END
```

As you see this is a very generic stored procedure! Reason for doing it like this is, that I have another table where it is possible to enter the above values and the the system will be able to build my end result.

But I'm kind of stocked right here. I have read the article: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/37938/Simple-6-steps-to-use-stored-procedure-in-LINQ where it is specified how to call a stored procedure. But one thing is that it seems that I should at least be able to define which table I am refering to (step 2)

And further, the above article does not describe how to add my arguments.

If it is possible to create the result by not using a stored procedure that would also be an option!

Comment: It doesn't do all that automatically when you drag the stored procedure from the data sources window into the dbml designer in Visual Studio?

Comment: Then the question is: Why not? You don't need to create a full entity model. Just add a LINQ to SQL Data Set and drag your SP into the view. Then you can call it.

Comment: You don't need to create a full entity model. Simply add a LINQ to SQL data source and drag the stored procedure into the view. Then you can call it. I've quickly glanced over the CodeProject article you linked, and basically they seem to be doing the same thing, only in code.

Comment: Thx a lot... Will give it a try and get back with the result. Also sorry for deleting a comment (right after your first comment). Reason was that I got something totally mixed up :-)

Comment: Oh, I was wondering already whether my internet connection had problems. We do have that problem here at work sometimes, so it didn't occur to me that you might have deleted it :-)

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work as is. The result is always an integer. If I change the Stored Procedure to dynamically insert into a table (SELECT @Field AS Field INTO tmpTable FROM @Table....) and then later in the SP says SELECT Field FROM tmpTable it still doesn't work. Then my DataClasses.dbml file complaints that it doesn't know which data type it should return. And I can only select INT as data type.

Comment: One thing that might work is that I can have two stored procedures: One that dynamically inserts the value into a tmpTable and another that simply makes a SELECT Field FROM tmpTable. This will only work 100% if I am sure that I can get the ID from the inserted value in my "creation sp". If I cannot, the data is not 100% certain to always work and then I cannot use it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay this is the work-around:

First I create a new table called TemporaryParking:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TemporaryParking](
[Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[Field] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_TemporaryParking] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  =     ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON, FILLFACTOR = 10) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

Next I create a stored procedure, which can polulate my table AND return the id of the new, inserted value:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[spGetConvertedFieldValue] 
-- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
@Table NVARCHAR(50),
@Field NVARCHAR(50),
@Key NVARCHAR(50),
@KeyValue NVARCHAR(500)
AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;

DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX)

SET @SQL = 'INSERT INTO TemporaryParking (Field) SELECT ' + @Field + ' FROM ' + @Table + ' WHERE ' + @Key + ' = ''' + @KeyValue + ''''

EXEC(@SQL)

RETURN @@Identity   
END
```

In my application I have created a .dbml file which 'contains' my stored procedure spGetConvertedFieldValue.

When calling this procedure it will return the Id from the inserted value and then I can create a simple LINQ statement where I get the value:

```
'lets assume that I now have the Id in a variable calle tmpId

var rv = (from f in _db.TemporaryParking
         where f.Id == tmpId
         select f.Field).First();
```

And if I want to, I can even clean up by deleting the value from the TemporaryParking again.

Thank you Thorsten Dittmar for pointing me in the right direction! Your answer didn't do the whole trick though.